# How to get data from JSON file with batch script and write the data into a text file?

Tags: json, batch-file

I would like to get data from a *.json file into `file.txt` with batch.

My JSON file `config.json`:

```
  "nodes": [
        {
          "id": "item1",
          "host": "${host:item1}",
          "apps": [
            {
              "id": "value1",
              "template_id": "value1"
            },
            {
              "id": "value2",
              "template_id": "value2",
            },
```

I want to get only the values `value1` and `value2` of `id` elements of node `apps`. But the problem on using the command `find` in my script is actually that it reads the values of `id` and `template_id`.

Is it possible to get the value to `id` and not `template_id`?

I tried this... still not working...

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set c=0
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:, " %%a in (' find "id" ^< "config.json" ') do (
    set /a c+=1
    set val[!c!]=%%~a
)
for /L %%b in (1,1,!c!) do echo !val[%%b]!
```

And after that, I don't know really how to get all these data in my text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't treat structured information as plain text.

If I take for example a `Valid JSON (RFC 4627)` version of your fragment:

```
{
    "nodes":[
    {
      "id":"item1",
      "host":"${host:item1}",
      "apps":[
         {
            "id":"value1",
            "template_id":"value1"
         },
         {
            "id":"value2",
            "template_id":"value2"
         }
      ]
    }]
}
```

And use PowerShell's cmdlet `ConvertFrom-Json` it's quite easy to receive the proper ID values

```
PoSh> $Json = Get-Content .\config.json | ConvertFrom-Json
PoSh> $JSon.Nodes.Apps.id
value1
value2
```

To be on topic with the batch-file tag wrapping this in a batch

```
@Echo off
Powershell -Nop -C "(Get-Content .\config.json|ConvertFrom-Json).Nodes.Apps.id" >file.txt
```

Comment: I have just another question, if i want to get in my .txt this values : item1 then value 1 and value 2. how can i do that with powershell ?

Comment: You' need to concatenate the information from different levels. `Powershell -Nop -C "(Get-Content .\config.json|ConvertFrom-Json).Nodes.id" >file.txt` and append the the other command to the file with `>>file.txt`

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Actuallys this working but if i have in my .json "item2" "value3" and "value4" if will show me : item1 - item2 - value1-value2-value3-value4 but it doesn't see me item1-value1-value2-item2-value3-value4 ?

Comment: Would have been nice to get this requirement from the beginning, in fact this is a new question. As you see by yourself wrapping only halfway ready solutions in another script language get's annoying. In the above powershell code the whole structure is contained in the variable $Json and you can access them directly with a (zero based) index. `$json.nodes[1].id`, `$json.nodes[1].apps.id`

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [**`jsonextractor.bat`**](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/master/hybrids/jscript/jsonextractor.bat) . In order to have a valid json I've used this:

```
{
    "nodes": [{
        "id": "item1",
        "host": "${host:item1}",
        "apps": [{
                "id": "value1",
                "template_id": "value1"
            },
            {
                "id": "value2",
                "template_id": "value2"
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

and to get the values:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('jsonextractor.bat test.json "nodes[0].apps[0].id"') do (
 set "first_id=%%~a"
)
echo %first_id%
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use a decent JSON parser, like [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html), to parse JSON!

```
xidel -s config.json -e "$json/(.//apps)()/id"   # or in full: $json/(nodes)()/(apps)()/id
value1
value2
```

To save the output to a file:

```
xidel -s config.json -e "$json/(.//apps)()/id" > output.txt
```