# How to efficiently extract specific sections of a video (Python/FFmpeg)?

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg

I have a bunch of videos for which I want to extract specific sections (either as videos or as frames). I get the specific sections from a .json file where the start and end frames are stored according to labels, like 'cat in video', 'dog in video'. I have an existing method in Python using opencv using the method mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67349721/how-to-save-specific-parts-of-video-into-separate-videos-using-opencv-in-python) but I found a one-liner using ffmpeg which is a lot more faster and efficient than my Python script, except that I have to manually fill in the start and end frames in this command.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf select='between(n\,x\,y)' -vsync 0 frames%d.png
```

I read a few questions about [working with .json files in a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53460823/how-to-get-data-from-json-file-with-batch-script-and-write-the-data-into-a-text) or [passing arguments to a batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24156912/passing-arguments-into-batch-file-via-python) which looks quite complicated and might spoil my system. Since I'm not familar working with .json files in a shell/batch script, I'm not sure how to start. Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to make a batch script that can read variables from a .json file and input it into my ffmpeg command?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already familiar with Python, I suggest you to use it to parse JSON files, then you can use [ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python) library, which is a ffmpeg binding for Python. It also has a [`crop`](https://kkroening.github.io/ffmpeg-python/#ffmpeg.crop) function, which I assume is what you need.

An alternative would be to use the `os.system('ffmpeg <arguments>')` calls from a Python script, which allows you to run external tools from the script.

Answer (score 0):

Python natively supports JSON with its builtin [`json` package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

As for doing this in python, here is an alternative approach that you can try my `ffmpegio-core` package:

```py
import ffmpegio

ffmpegio.transcode('in.mp4','frames%d.png',vf=f"select='between(n\,{x}\,{y})'",vsync=0)
```

If the videos are constant frame rate, it could be faster to specify the start and end timestamps as input options:

```py
fs = ffmpegio.probe.video_streams_basic('in.mp4')[0]['frame_rate']
ffmpegio.transcode('in.mp4', 'frames%d.png', ss_in=x/fs, to_in=y/fs, vsync=0)
```

If you don't know the frame rate, you are calling ffprobe and ffmpeg for each file, so there is a tradeoff. But if your input video is long, it could be worthwhile.

But if speed is your primary goal, calling FFmpeg directly always is the fastest.

[`ffmpegio` GitHub repo](https://github.com/python-ffmpegio/python-ffmpegio)